# Find and Replace Percent Signs - Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove the percent signs in the following data list.  This way I can change all the numbers to floats.  I've tried a few different options `string.strip()`, etc..  However, I can't seem to find a way that sticks.  I think this has to do with the fact that strings are immutable, but I'm not sure.

My question is how would I remove the `%` signs from the following list?

```
[['5.71666666667', '2.08%', '11.03%', '13.89%'], ['5.7', '1.36%', '3.04%', '3.90%'], ['5.48333333333', '1.49%', '2.30%', '2.60%']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As strings are immutable You just need to create new list with modified strings

for example if Your list stored in data variable:

```
data = [['5.71666666667', '2.08%', '11.03%', '13.89%'],
        ['5.7', '1.36%', '3.04%', '3.90%'],
        ['5.48333333333', '1.49%', '2.30%', '2.60%']]
```

You can strip each element

```
data = [[i.strip('%') for i in j] for j in data]
```

or replace percent sign with empty string

```
data = [[i.replace('%', '') for i in j] for j in data]
```

But You should check instance type is list can contains anything but strings otherwise You got `AttributeError`

```
data = [[i.replace('%', '') if isinstance(i, basestring) else i 
                                      for i in j] for j in data]
```

You can not to create new lists but iterate over existing lists ang modify them:

```
for sublist in data:
    for i, val in enumerate(sublist):
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            sublist[i] = v.strip('%')
```

Comment: As lists are mutable, you actually don't need to create a new list. But I admit that it's simpler this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution mutating the list. but you should probably prefer olegs solution, it's simpler.

```
input = [['5.71666666667', '2.08%', '11.03%', '13.89%'], ['5.7', '1.36%', '3.04%', '3.90%'], ['5.48333333333', '1.49%', '2.30%', '2.60%']]

for sublist in input:
    for i, s in enumerate(sublist):
        sublist[i] = s.strip('%')
print input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[float(j.strip('%')) for j in i] for i in data]
```

---

This code iterates through all the lists in the main list, and then in turn all the strings in those embedded lists. And for each of those strings, it replaces them using:

```
float(j.strip('%'))
```

Where `j` is each string.